# Node.js SOA with JSON web-services - configuration

Tags: json, web-services, node.js, configuration, soa

I am starting research on how to implement Node.js [SOA (service oriented architecture)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_oriented_architecture) with JSON web-services.

As a small sub-question, I need an approach/framework/system to make universal configuration center for all companies web-services. So that we don't configure every application with exact address of other application, but just link to some central server to get that information. 
(This should be very well worked-out topic for XML-based services, so some terminology/approaches/etc could/should be borrowed.)

Related to 
[RESTful JSON based SOA Registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630762/restful-json-based-soa-registry)
[Service Oriented Architecture suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105093/service-oriented-architecture-suggestions)

UPDATE: This questions is about web-services configuration & orchestration.

Comment: take a look here: http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/10/creating-a-rest-api-using-node-js-express-and-mongodb/

Comment: "As a small sub-question, I need an approach/framework/system to make universal configuration centre for all companies web-services" This is not a good thing to do, because it would create a dependency on your services to the "central" configuration system. They need to be units that can be deployed individually.

Comment: @Marco If one services is used by several others and it needs to be moved to other server (for example when upgrade or failure), then having one configuration point solve problem of other services using different entry points.

Comment: @PaulVerest Let me get this clear. In a SOA environment, services need to be independent of other services, at deployment and at run-time. You must be able to deploy the service and to run it without depending on others, but services are of no use if they can't communicate with each other, and your question is completely valid. The only problem with centralized configuration is that, if the resource is not available your server won't be able to run. There are of course ways to solve this.

Comment: @PaulVerest You can for example rely on strong SLA's to make sure that that resource is almost "always" available, maybe a cloud provider (Amazon, Azure), but it really depends on how your services are laid over to be honest.

Comment: @PaulVerest But if you're running in the same network then you won't need any cloud provider you can even use just a network path containing something like a xml file, what you have to make sure if that if that resource is not available you service must still work. In many case what I just said makes no sense, because one of your services might need to communicate with other services, and if there is no configuration "at that time", service communication will be unavailable, but that is why aysn operations with the use of queues come handy.

Answer (score -1):

GO for an active(having activity happening off late) framework with lean architecture.There's one called [Geddy](http://geddyjs.org/) and another called [Restify](http://mcavage.github.io/node-restify/). If in doubt, Express can also be used for building webservices with JSON.

You can work on reading the centrally stored config from different app codebse when you use any of these.

Comment: Could you add links at least for GO & Geddy